# How do I execute Perl script in Java when we give two arguments with command (input and output)

Tags: java, perl, ubuntu

I have developed myself tagger and I want to host on the web. My server is based on jsp. But this tagger is based on svmtool and it has been written in Perl script. That's why, I have created one ".java" file. In this file I've created Processor builder and via the Runtime.getRuntime().exec through this process I am calling this file.

It is working but it doesn't show my output. Plz help to solve this issue. For the better under standing below I am giving my java code and also given last line of output/stop the process:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ExeCommand {
String outS = "", errS="";

        try {

        // run the Unix "type your  terminal command" command
            System.out.println ("Running tagger!");
String command = "perl /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/bin/SVMTagger.pl -V 4 -S LRL /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/models/ih/IN < /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/tests.txt > /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/output.txt";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command

            System.out.println("It will take time so keep the patience:\n" + command);
System.out.println ("First error line: " + stdError.readLine());

            // read any errors from the attempted command
System.out.println("Please check your command (if any):\n");
            while ((errS = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Error:\t" + errS);
            }
stdError.close();


        System.out.println ("First output line: " + stdInput.readLine());
            while ((outS = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Output:\t" + outS);
            }
stdInput.close();

             System.out.println("Finished!");           
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("found exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.exit(-1);  
        }
    System.out.println("Finished all!");
    }
}
```

And, It is a little bit working. After stream input reader it is never work. Here, Please suggest me how to solve this issue and I am also giving my terminal output :

```
$ java ExeCommand 

It will take time so keep the patience:
Please check your command (if any):
SVMTool v1.3 (C) 2006 TALP RESEARCH CENTER.
Written by Jesus Gimenez and Lluis Marquez.
MODEL = /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/bin/HIN
T = 0 (F = 1) :: S = LRL :: K = 0 :: U = 0
READING DICTIONARY </home/svmtool_v1.3.2/bin/HIN.DICT>...
[DONE] READING MODELS < DIRECTION = left-to-right :: MODEL = ambiguous context > (1) READING MODELS (weights and biases) FOR KNOWN WORDS ... (2) READING MODELS (weights and biases) FOR UNKNOWN WORDS ... READING MODELS < DIRECTION = right-to-left :: MODEL = ambiguous context > (1) READING MODELS (weights and biases) FOR KNOWN WORDS ... (2) READING MODELS (weights and biases) FOR UNKNOWN WORDS ... TAGGING < DIRECTION = left-to-right then right-to-left
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the command again:

`String command = "perl /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/bin/SVMTagger.pl -V 4 -S LRL /home/svmtool_v1.3.2/models/ih/IN < /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/tests.txt > /home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/output.txt";`

All the output of the command is being redirected to `/home/tomcat4.1.40/webapps/pos/textfile/output.txt`, which is why the input stream is not getting any data. Removing the redirection should fix the issue.